# Get file names of executed spec files

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, protractor, jasmine-spec-reporter

How do I get a file name of currently executed spec? 
For example:
I run: `protractor conf.js --specs ./spec/first_spec.js,./spec/second_spec.js`

so I want to retrieve array `['first_spec','second_spec']`, because I want to show it in a `report.html`. Is this a good way of thinking or is there a built-in function for file names in the latest run? I'm new to protractor and angular, and I found only a way to extract individual `describe` which doesn't really help me. I write this on top of `protractor-angular-screenshot-reporter`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one way of doing it. Read the array of test cases passed from CLI arguments and use it as per your convenience

```
onPrepare: function() {
var testCaseArr
    for (i = 0; i < process.argv.length; i++) {
        argument = process.argv[i];
        // if "specs" are found we know that the immediate following object is the array of test scenarios
        if (argument.indexOf('specs')>0) {
            specIndex = i + 1;
            testCaseArr = process.argv[i+1];
            break;
        }
    }
    // This will output - ['first_spec','second_spec']
    console.log(testCaseArr)
},
```

Please refer my [blog post](https://testautomation-aditya.com/2016/12/27/how-to-access-run-time-cli-arguments-at-when-running-protractor-tests/) for more details on the same.

Comment: Works great! Thank you.